# Date format issue

Tags: vb.net, parsing, datetime, visual-studio-2003, asp.net-1.1

I'm facing problem while conversion of date

if I used -- Date.parse("28/01/2011")
it gives me error as

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

so then I modify above code as -- CDate("28/01/2011")
it gives me error as

> "Cast from string "28/01/2011" to type 'Date' is not valid."

I used convert.todatetime also date.parseexact but nothing is working...

I'm using VS2003 in asp.net1.1 with vb.net

Answer (score 3):

Probably Parse is using InvariantCulture date format "MM/dd/yyyy". Maybe you can try with

```
DateTime.ParseExact("28/01/2011", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or passing a correct culture on Parse, like spanish that has date format dd/MM/yyyy

```
Date.Parse("28/01/2011", new CultureInfo("es-ES", true));
```

Write from memory, maybe is not accurate